# Install/enable sqlsrv & pdo_sqlsrv drivers for php8.1 on ubuntu20.0

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv, php-8.1

I am trying to enable sqlsrv drivers for php8.1 on Ubuntu 20.0. It is not showing the extension in `phpinfo()`.

When trying to check the sqlsrv module with commmand `php -m`, the output is like this:

[image]

I have followed official documentation below:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-ver16
- Tried to add extension(`extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so`, `extension=sqlsrv.so`) in /etc/php/8.1/apache2/php.ini

I am not sure what went wrong, any suggestion is appreciated.

> ```
> The output of phpinfo() for php7.4:
> ```

[image: List item]

> ```
> The output of phpinfo() for php8.1:
> ```

[image]

Here are the things:

- PHP 7.4 and 8.1 installed on my machine.
- The sqlsrv drivers works fine for php7.4 version
- When trying to install/enable for php8.1 it does not work at all.

What I am missing here?

Comment: did you restart apache after adding the extension in the php.ini file?

Comment: @SamuelCook Yes I have restart apache after adding extension.

Comment: @SamuelCook I have updated question with more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
1. switch to php8.1
2. sudo pecl uninstall -r sqlsrv 
3. sudo pecl uninstall -r pdo_sqlsrv 
4. sudo pecl -d php_suffix=7.2 install sqlsrv
5. sudo pecl -d php_suffix=7.2 install pdo_sqlsrv
6. sudo service apache2 restart
```

Note that `-r, --register-only` do not remove files but only register the packages as not installed.

Checkout this resource for more info.
https://github.com/microsoft/msphpsql/issues/1145#issuecomment-649682231

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by adding below commands.

```
pecl install sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv
printf "; priority=20\nextension=sqlsrv.so\n" > /etc/php/8.1/mods-available/sqlsrv.ini
printf "; priority=30\nextension=pdo_sqlsrv.so\n" > /etc/php/8.1/mods-available/pdo_sqlsrv.ini
phpenmod -v 8.1 sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv
```

after that need to restart apache2