# LINUX PDO_SQLSRV Could not find driver unable to connect

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, pdo

Hoping you can help. I am running Linux Ubunto 22.04 with PHP8.1.

I installed the sqlsrv drivers following this page: [Loading the Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/loading-the-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-ver16#loading-the-driver-at-php-startup)

I am still getting a 'could not find driver' error message on PDO("sqlsrv:server=

I had to install the drivers by downloading the pre-built drivers (package Ubuntu2204-8.1). I copied the driver files to /usr/lib/php/20210902', based on: php -i | grep extension_dir

- extension_dir => /usr/lib/php/20210902 => /usr/lib/php/20210902

The file '10-pdo.ini' was pre-existing in /etc/php/8.1/apache2/conf.d/.

I created a new file '30-pdo-sqlsrv' as instructed linking to 'extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_82_nts.so'.

I added the following to the bottom of my php.ini file: extension=php_sqlsrv_81_nts.so (I checked that I edited the correct php.ini file by checking the path in phpinfo:/etc/php/8.1/apache2/php.ini)

I have restarted my server ('sudo service apache2 restart'), and I list my PHP modules ('php -m'). The list shows, amonsgt others: PDO and pdo_sqlsrv.

PHPINFO lists the following:
PDO
PDO support enabled
PDO drivers mysql
pdo_mysql
PDO Driver for MySQL    enabled
Client API version  mysqlnd 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14
Directive   Local Value Master Value
pdo_mysql.default_socket    /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

I can see nothing about pdo_sqlsrv

I created some code to test the connection:

```
    if (!function_exists('mysqli_init') && !extension_loaded('mysqli')) 
{
    echo '!!We don\'t have mysqli!!!'. "<br>";
} 
else 
{
    echo 'msyqli function exists.'. "<br>";
}
$mysqli = null;

if (!extension_loaded('pdo')) 
{
    echo 'We don\'t have PDO!!!'. "<br>";
} 
else 
{
    echo 'PDO extension loaded.'. "<br>";
}



// pdo_sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv
if (!function_exists('pdo_sqlsrv')) 
{
    echo '!!pdo_sqlsrv does not exist!!!'. "<br>";
} 
else 
{
    echo 'pdo_sqlsrv extension exists.'. "<br>";
}
if (!extension_loaded('pdo_sqlsrv')) 
{
    echo '!!pdo_sqlsrv not loaded!!!'. "<br>";
} 
else 
{
    echo 'pdo_sqlsrv extension loaded.'. "<br>";
}

try
{
$connection = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$servername;Database=$database", $user, $password);


} 
catch (PDOException $e) 
{
    echo 'PDO Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage(). "<br>";
}
```

My code outputs the following:

- msyqli function exists.
- PDO extension loaded.
- !!pdo_sqlsrv does not exist!!!
- !!pdo_sqlsrv not loaded!!!
- PDO Connection failed: could not find driver

Can anyone point me to something that I might have missed? Why is this not working? Am I barking up the wrong tree with what I have tried?

Comment: From my past experience you will need to execute commands like `pecl install sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv` . See whether [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74422334/install-enable-sqlsrv-pdo-sqlsrv-drivers-for-php8-1-on-ubuntu20-0) can give you some hints

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have PECL installed. It is a work network computer, an international company, and IT have been unable to install PECL.

Comment: Pls check whether the php.ini you edited is the one for PHP CLI or apache

Comment: Have you read through the article, [Linux and macOS Installation Tutorial for the Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac) yet?

Comment: Are you using PHP 8.1 or PHP 8.2? Because you said PHP 8.1 early in the question, yet it seems like you're trying to reference PHP 8.2 drivers with `php_pdo_sqlsrv_82_nts.so`.

Comment: "Are you using PHP 8.1 or PHP 8.2? Because you said PHP 8.1 early in the question, yet it seems like you're trying to reference PHP 8.2 drivers with php_pdo_sqlsrv_82_nts.so" - Sorry a typo, the line was php_pdo_sqlsrv_81_nts.so

Comment: AHA! I just double checked my 30-pdo_sql.ini file. That was the issue. I now get the following: msyqli function exists.
PDO extension loaded.
!!pdo_sqlsrv does not exist!!!
pdo_sqlsrv extension loaded.
PDO Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HYT00]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired

Comment: `PDO Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HYT00]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired`, does `$servername` contain a valid IP address or host name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up re-installing drivers for sqlsrv.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).